# Is there a way to reduce/optimize multiple .copyValuesToRange statements?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to optimize my script. Part of the script has multiple .copyValuesToRange statements. Is there a way to optimize the following?

```
    const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let source = SS.getSheetByName("Update List");
    let destination = SS.getSheetByName("Power Level");

    source.getRange('TIER1Master').copyValuesToRange(destination, 12, 12, 6, 29);
    source.getRange('TIER2Master').copyValuesToRange(destination, 15, 15, 6, 13);
    source.getRange('TIER3Master').copyValuesToRange(destination, 15, 15, 16, 23);
    source.getRange('PINNACLE1Master').copyValuesToRange(destination, 18, 18, 6, 23);
    source.getRange('PINNACLE2Master').copyValuesToRange(destination, 21, 21, 6, 29);
    source.getRange('MasterListTimestamp').copyValuesToRange(destination, 15, 15, 1, 1);
```

I've used .getRangeList in other areas of my script that were given the same value but I don't know if that can be applied here since the values are different and from different sized ranges.

I'm new to learning Apps Script, javascript & coding in general. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That should run pretty fast. If you are running that inside a loop, it may be that it is the loop that needs attention. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm told that the Sheets API is very fast.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you. It takes about 3.5 seconds in the 'if' block that it's in. It's not running in a loop. Just thought I could reduce it more.

Comment: The code you show seems fine. Chances are that the bad performance you mention is caused by the _spreadsheet_ rather than the script. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).